# Looking for delimiters similar to ceil

Tags: amsmath, delimiters

I want to use brackets similar to lceil, rceil and lfoor, rfloor, but with the vertical lines on both sides at an angle. Does anything like this already exist? If not, would it be difficult to create them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need them to auto-scale, here is a `pdflatex` solution. See ADDENDUM for scalable version.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,mathtools}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]
  {%
    \mbox
      {%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
      }%
  }
\newcommand\lsceil{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[.2]{$\SavedStyle\lceil$}}}
\newcommand\rsceil{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[-.2]{$\,\SavedStyle\rceil$}}}
\newcommand\lsfloor{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[-.2]{$\,\SavedStyle\lfloor$}}}
\newcommand\rsfloor{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[+.2]{$\SavedStyle\rfloor\,$}}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\sceils}{\lsceil}{\rsceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\sfloors}{\lsfloor}{\rsfloor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
x\sceils{A}y \quad x\sfloors{A}y 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,mathtools}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]
  {%
    \mbox
      {%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
      }%
  }
%\newcommand\lsceil{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[.2]{$\SavedStyle\lceil$}}}
%\newcommand\rsceil{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[-.2]{$\,\SavedStyle\rceil$}}}
%\newcommand\lsfloor{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[-.2]{$\,\SavedStyle\lfloor$}}}
%\newcommand\rsfloor{\ThisStyle{\slantbox[+.2]{$\SavedStyle\rfloor\,$}}}
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\newcommand\sceils[1]{\ThisStyle{\savebox\tmpbox{$\SavedStyle\mkern-1mu#1$}%
  \slantbox[.2]{$\SavedStyle\left\lceil\vphantom{\usebox{\tmpbox}}\right.$}%
  \usebox{\tmpbox}%
  \slantbox[-.2]{$\SavedStyle\left.\vphantom{\usebox{\tmpbox}}\right\rceil$}%
}}
\newcommand\sfloors[1]{\ThisStyle{\savebox\tmpbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}\mkern1mu%
  \slantbox[-.2]{$\SavedStyle\left\lfloor\vphantom{\usebox{\tmpbox}}\right.$}%
  \usebox{\tmpbox}%
  \slantbox[.2]{$\SavedStyle\left.\vphantom{\usebox{\tmpbox}}\right\rfloor$}%
}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
x\sceils{A}y \quad x\sfloors{A}y 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x}{y}\sceils{\frac{x}{y}}\frac{x}{y} \quad 
x\sfloors{\frac{x}{y}}y 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! thats exactly what I was looking for. Of course auto-scale will probably eventually come in handy, but this is already great.

Comment: @Larry Please see my revision for a scalable variety.  Hoever, they only work in pairs (a scalable `\lsceil` and `\rsceil` are not provided)